# Vector layer points are not being imported/shown from MySQL datasource

Tags: vector-layer, mysql

## Issue

QGis 3.24.12 does not visualise/import points from a vector layer with a MySQL datasource anymore.

In QGis 3.24.12, I import a table from a MySQL datasource as a vector layer. However, the points are not being visualized. I suspect QGis is not importing the data correctly.

I classified this as a bug because this worked fine in QGis 3.04. I had to upgrade because my SQL provider does not accept the TLS version used by QGis 3.04 anymore.

## Context

In the images below following can be observed: The *coord* (coordinate) column from the MySQL database, containing the points that need to be plotted, is missing from the QGis table structure.
I suspect that is the reason why QGis is not plotting/visualizing any points.
It looks like QGis is incorrectly converting the *coord* column into a *geometry* column.
Compare images below:

### MySQL table structure

The *coord* column is a "point" datatype:
[image: MySQL table structure]

### QGis 3.24.12 table structure

The *coord* column is missing, a *geometry* column is added
[image: QGis table structure]

### MySQL record example

The *coord* column contains coordinates:
[image: MySQL record example]

### QGis 3.24.12 example record:

The *geometry* column only contains the word "POINT"
[image: QGis record example]

## Questions

- Is this a bug in QGis? This worked fine in QGis 3.04
- Should I reconfigure my MySQL table to use another datatype than "point" in order for QGis to correctly import the coordinates.

## Steps to reproduce

1. layer > add layer > vector layer
2. In the vector layer panel:

> ```
> source type: database
> encoding automatic
>
> Database Type: mysql
> Connections: myconnection
> ```

> ```
> Test Connection > Succesful
> ```

> ```
> add
> ```

3. select items to add: *tableWithCoordinates* (shown in image above) > add layers
4. Check attributes of imported layer -> *coord* column is missing, *geometry* column is added as described above
5. I get following warning but I think it is unrelated:

> ```
> this layer appears to have no projection specification. by default, this..
> ```

> ```
> Choose: BD72 / Belgian Lambert 72
> ```